# When a business closes, how to transfer the rankings and domain authority from its website to another?

Tags: 301-redirect, ranking, website-features, domain-authority

We have two restaurants A & B, restaurant A is closing and we want all the traffic to redirect to restaurant B website. As restaurant B will offer some of the menu offered by A.

Restaurant A has more traffic and ranks better than B should we redirect all Page of A to Home Page of B to improve rankings with 301 redirect or this is a wrong strategy?

What should I do so that I can transfer domain authority of domain A to B without hurting domain B's rankings?

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely not setup 301 redirects right away. Instead, update Restaurant A's home page, headers, footers, and any relevant landing pages to inform customers of the change.

Use language and images that are bold, very clear, and explain the change plainly -- don't just add links that whisk cusomters away to the Restaurant B website.

Maybe include something like a button with text "Yes, show me Restaurant B!"

Have the menu items from Restaurant A that will be offered at Restaurant B prominently featured on Website A, with links for ordering or more information that will direct them to the same menu items on Website B.

I think you would also want to actively promote the change on social media and/or email, especially in the beginning. After a while it's possible that Google might interpret your modified Site A pages as being soft redirects, which rank lower. But ideally that won't matter much as time passes and Website B gains traction.

Comment: Business is already closed as informed by client. now object to redirect user to site B so that site will get traffic of Site A and also Site B will have some Menu Items added from Site A... Restaurant A i already closed and client didnt inform me about any changes Client wants Site A traffic to be redirected to Site B... So i wanted to know on a expert leave will this move hurt site B as there are no relevant connects from of pages.. Usually we redirect from A to B where URL has changed but contents are same?